# Output of tests in command line jasmine karma grunt

Tags: gruntjs, jasmine, karma-runner

How do I get the grunt karma test runner to output the result of the test in the command line.
I have tried setting the reporter to 'progress' but that does not show me the name of the test that ran

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to choose a different reporter for karma: progress and dots are minimal reporters.
Here's [a list of reporters](https://www.npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-reporter) from npm.

Personally I would recommend `karma-story-reporter`